# Proof verification regarding $\epsilon>0$ being arbitrary.

Tags: analysis, self-learning

Let $f:(\mathbb{R}, \tau_c) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ be a function (the topologies don't play a role here),  $z\in\mathbb{R}$ a given point and assume $\forall \epsilon>0, [f^{-1}(z-\epsilon,z+\epsilon)]^c=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\mid f(x)-z\mid \geq \epsilon \}:=A_{\epsilon}$ is countable . I want to show that as $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary then actually all $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus  \{ z\})$  is countable.

---

Looking at $A_ \epsilon=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\mid f(x)-z\mid \geq \epsilon \}$ if $x \in A_ \epsilon :f(x)=z$ were possible, then $0\geq \epsilon>0$ which is a contradiction. Otherwise, if $x \in A_ \epsilon:f(x) \neq z$ then it is possible since there will always have an $ \epsilon>0: \mid  f(x)-z\mid  \geq \epsilon$. I conclude that there are only countable points such that $x \in  f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus  \{ z\})$.

Do you think it is ok?

Another aproach would be to set $\epsilon=1/n$ and then show that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty f^{-1}[(-\infty,z-1/n]\cup [1/n+z,\infty)]=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{z\})$ which is countable since each preimage is countable and the countable union of them is also countable.
So, as $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, in particular, $\{A_{1/n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are a collection of countable sets whose union is countable. If $x\in \cup_{\epsilon>0}A_\epsilon$, then $x$ is in some $A_\epsilon$ and $\exists n: 1/n<\epsilon$ and then $\mid f(x)-z\mid\geq \epsilon>1/n$. Hence $x\in A_{1/n}\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_{1/n}$. Analogously, if $x \in \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_{1/n}$, then $x\in A_{1/n}$ for some $n$, and $\exists \epsilon>0:1/n>\epsilon$. This leads to $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_{1/n}=\cup_{\epsilon>0}A_\epsilon$.

**Are both approach acceptable?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you first approach you did not consider the possibility there may be uncountable many $\epsilon$. In other words you have shown simply that if $x \in f^{-1}(\mathbb R / {z}), \exists\epsilon > 0, x \in A_\epsilon$ and if for some $\epsilon$ $x \in A_\epsilon, x \in f^{-1}(\mathbb R / {z}) $. This does not rule out the case that the set is uncountable since there are uncountable many $\epsilon$.

Your second approach is absolutely correct and the best way to go in fact.

Comment: So I can start saying that "as $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, in particular, $\{A_{1/n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ are a collection of countable sets whose union is countable", and ignore all the remaining uncountable $\epsilon$'s? I think I can say that $\cup_{\epsilon>0}A_{\epsilon}=\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_{1/n}$, but how to argue it?

Comment: If $x\in \cup_{\epsilon>}A_\epsilon$, then $x$ is in some $A_\epsilon$ and $\exists n: 1/n<\epsilon$ and then $\mid f(x)-z\mid\geq \epsilon>1/n$. Hence $x\in \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_{1/n}$. Analogously, the converse is true...

Comment: Yes you can tailor your first argument this way but by doing so you are already using your second approach anyways

Comment: But is it necessary, for the second approach, to show that $\cup_{\epsilon>0}A_{\epsilon}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{1/n}$? It does not makes sense to me, if I just consider the particular cases $\epsilon=1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}$ and forget the uncountable remaining $\epsilon$'s.

Comment: Yes you are right, its only necessary to take $\epsilon = 1/n$ for your second approach. It can be however used in your first approach is what I am getting at by showing $f^{-1}(\mathbb R / {z}) = \cup_{\epsilon>0}A_{\epsilon}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{1/n}$